# How to know what size a char array stores

Tags: c

I am writing a dummy example to simulate buffer overflow attack.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void target() {
printf("You overflowed successfully, gg");
exit(0);
}
void vulnerable(char* str1) {
char buf[5];
strcpy(buf, str1);
}
int main() {
printf("%d",sizeof(char));
vulnerable("abcdefghijklmnop");
printf("This only prints in normal control flow");
}
```

I have checked the size of char which is 1.Here my buffer size is 5 but it is still able to hold 16 values before going to segmentation fault. How is this possible. I know I am missing something in basics. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: You are missing the concept of *undefined behavior*. When a program is doing something illegal and invoking it, it can crash. Or not crash. Or do some other weird things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you share some documentation or links so I can learn more about this@EugeneSh.

Comment: https://www.wikiod.com/w/C_Undefined_behavior

Comment: What is there to understand? You allocate a buffer that can hold only 5 `char`s.  You are trying to copy 17 `char`s into that buffer. Overflow occurs, writing the extra `char`s into surrounding memory, corrupting that memory, if not crashing. Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Ultimately, this is undefined behavior by the C language specifications. In other words, compilers may implement the assembling of your code differently. As for "why" does this occur - I can say with certainty that increasing the size of the string you pass to `vulnerable` will _eventually_ cause your program to crash. Your code _is_ overflowing the buffer, but it likely isn't currently crashing because there is padding, stack canaries, or a memory layout that isn't causing the current string to overflow outside of the stack frame. If you want to see why specifically, disassemble the binary.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was about to write up a simple answer explaining UB, but in this case I don't think it's the correct explanation. I mean, the code obviously invokes UB, but the entire point is a buffer overflow attack, which is UB by definition and yet can be made to reliably work under the right assumptions.

Comment: Thats the thing it is not overflowing till 16 element @RemyLebeau

Comment: Yes, it is overflowing, once you try to copy more than 5 `char`s into the buffer. The remaining 12 `char`s are still copied, into memory that is *following* the buffer. But like h0r53 explained, there MAY be some safety built-in by the compiler to mitigate the effects of the overflow, depending on compiler, configuration, architecture, etc. There is just not enough info provided to explain what is actually going on. In any case, this code is *susceptible* to an overflow, but it is not *exploiting* the overflow to make `target()` be called. Which I assume is the whole point of this exercise?

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde The code is vulnerable (and exploitable) only with certain assumptions, which are not general at all. One can think of implementing a compiler that will enforce compile-time bounds check and will be fully C-standard compliant. So under such a compiler this program won't be vulnerable or exploitable.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde I mean going into the subject of exploiting certain UBs before the actual understanding what UB is for me is putting the cart before the horses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot stress enough that this is undefined behavior. Compilers are not obligated by the C standard to support this behavior and their implementations will vary.

However, to illuminate the issue you are experiencing and hopefully provide insights into what may be occurring, here is an example.

I compiled your code using https://godbolt.org/, x86-64 gcc 11.1, with the `-m32` flag. Here is the notable assembly for the vulnerable function.

```
vulnerable(char*):
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 24
        sub     esp, 8
        push    DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
        lea     eax, [ebp-13]
        push    eax
        call    strcpy
        add     esp, 16
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

At a high level, this is what is happening:

1. The stack frame is adjusted such that the previous `ebp` is pushed on the stack at the new location of `ebp`, which is the previous `esp`. Then 32 bytes are subtracted to extend the new stack frame.
2. The argument to this function (technically a char*) is stored at `ebp+8` by the calling convention used
3. The memory location of `buf` is at `ebp-13`.
4. `strcpy` is called with the two parameters that you would expect, `buf` and the function argument.

So by this implementation, you would have to write 13 bytes into `buf` before overwriting the value of the previous base pointer at `ebp`. You would need an additional 4 bytes to overwrite the return address (which would be located at `ebp+4`). `strcpy` includes the null-terminator character. So technically calling `vulnerable("abcdefghijklmnop")` is copying 17 characters into `buf`. But as I mentioned earlier, `buf` is at `ebp-13` and the return address is at `ebp+4`, so writing 17 bytes will overflow the return address and almost certainly result in a segfault.

It's worth noting that overwriting the return address will almost always cause a segfault (in the case of exploits, overwriting the return address to something "valid" can result in code execution). It's also worth noting that corrupting the value of the previous `ebp` will corrupt the stack frame of the previous function, but it may not result in a crash. In this case it likely isn't crashing your program because you simply return to `main` and then exit.

**Exploiting Buffer Overflows**

If you are interested in exploiting this vulnerability, you need to use the information I provided above to craft a payload. Let's say you want to call the `target` function. You first need to identify the address of that function in memory. Assuming features such as Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) and Position Independent Code (PIC) are turned off, then your functions will be loaded into consistent memory locations. One way to determine the address of `target` is by disassembling the binary by attaching a debugger or using a tool such as `objdump`. Let's say the address of `target` is 0x0408aab0. Then all you need to do is replace the location of the return address on the stack with that value. Let's put it all together.

1. The address of `target` is 0x0408aab0 (hypothetically)
2. The return address is at `ebp+4`
3. The return address is 16 bytes away from your buffer

Thus,

Your payload would look like: 16_byte_padding + 0x0408aab0. Depending on the endianness of your system, you may need to write the address bytes in reverse. Under these assumptions you could generate such a payload with `python -c "print 'A'*16 + '\xb0\xaa\x08\x04'"`